# Can't run Robotium on Android Studio with only APK

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, robotium, ui-testing

In the description of Robotium, it says it's able to test Android projects with just the APK. I am capable of doing this in Eclipse but I can't seem to do this in Android Studio. When taking the same code from Eclipse and using it in Android Studio, I cannot load the launcher class for the app that I am trying to test.

Does anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to try Robotium Recorder for Android Studio. It will create test projects for APK:s. You can check how it does it and then do it the same way your self.

Comment: But Robotium Recorder isn't free